# Dynamic and Immutable UIElement Arrays

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, list, uielement

I have a `WrapPanel` that contains multiple `Canvas` of the same size. Each `Canvas` has some `UIElement`s (i.e. `TextBox`, `TextBlock`, `Button`s etc) as children. The creation of each `Canvas` (including its `UIElement` children) and the number of `Canvas` to be created are all done in run-time code behind (no XAML).

Initially I did the following, which works:

```
// declare as class properties, so all function can access them
WrapPanel wp = new WrapPanel();
Canvas[] cv = new Canvas[500];
TextBox[] tb = new TextBox[500];

// A function (e.g. a Button_Click event) that generates multiple Canvas in a WrapPanel
for (int i = 0; i<myInt; i++)
{
cv[i] = new Canvas();
tb[i] = new TextBox();
cv[i].Children.Add(tb[i]);
wp.Children.Add(cv[i]);
}
```

The above code is straight forwards works OK - Until I implement add, minus and destroy buttons where I could

```
1. Add an additional `Canvas` on a click event
2. Remove the last `Canvas` on a click event
3. Destroy a specific `Canvas` in the `WrapPanel` on a click event (may ba a little cross icon in each `Canvas`)
```

If I process some combination of the above 3 actions, I could easily create UIElements of the same index or create Canvas that goes out of the range of what it had been declared initially.

I looked into **List** however, each Canvas have different properties (each also has UIElement Children with different properties) and I can't figure out how List would solve it. A way for me to go around that is to declare a super large Array size for Canvas (e.g. **Canvas[] cv = new Canvas[99999]** but I though that's not very efficient.

Also, if I use List, how could I change properties of a specific UIElement after the they are generated? E.g. If i add 10 Canvas and add to List, and after they are all generated, I need to select the 5th Canvas and change a TextBox.Text, how do I access it like I did in an Array (i.e. tb[5].Text = "Hello")?

Can anyone show me some approaches to this problem?

Comment: If you need an array that can shrink/grow then you're asking for a list. Can you elaborate on why a List wouldn't work in your case?

Comment: @vanja, I edited my question which hope should clarify the problem.

Comment: 1. Don't use parallel lists. Make a type that represents each entry in full, and keep a single list of that type, not several lists where each only has part of the story. 2. You really should be looking into MVVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a direct translation on how to do this with a list instead below. Given your code I don't know why you want to keep track of the canvas and textbox'es in a list - you can just access the children collection of the `WrapPanel` directly instead - let's assume you do need these separate collections for now.

```
 WrapPanel wp = new WrapPanel();
 List<Canvas> cvList = new List<Canvas>();
 List<TextBox> tbList = new List<TextBox>();

 public void Init()
{

    int myInt = 500;
    // in a function (e.g. a Button_Click event) to generate the multiple Canvas in a WrapPanel
    for (int i = 0; i < myInt; i++)
    {
        Canvas cv = new Canvas();
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        cv.Children.Add(tb);
        wp.Children.Add(cv);

        cvList.Add(cv);
        tbList.Add(tb);
    }
}


public void AddCanvas()
{
    Canvas cv = new Canvas();
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    cv.Children.Add(tb);
    wp.Children.Add(cv);
    cvList.Add(cv);
    tbList.Add(tb);
}

public void RemoveCanvas()
{
        wp.Children.RemoveAt(wp.Children.Count-1);
        cvList.RemoveAt(cvList.Count - 1);
        tbList.RemoveAt(cvList.Count - 1);
}
```

**Edit** for added comment:

> E.g. If i add 10 Canvas, and after
>   they are all generated, I need to
>   select the 5th Canvas and change a
>   TextBox.Text, how do I access it like
>   I did in an Array (i.e. tb[5].Text =
>   "Hello")?

You can just access the children directly. You know you only added `Canvas` elements to your `WrapPanel`. So you could do (wp is the `WrapPanel` again):

```
TextBox textbox = (wp.Children[5] as Canvas).Children[0] as TextBox;
textbox.Text = "Hello";
```

Comment: I'm with @BrokenGlass - seems to make sense in this case that you just want to be able to manage children in the WrapPanel's collection.

Comment: thanks. But then how could I change properties of a specific UIElement? E.g. If i add 10 Canvas, and after they are all generated, I need to select the 5th Canvas and change a TextBox.Text, how do I access it like I did in an Array (i.e. tb[5].Text = "Hello")?

Comment: @KMC - Canvas c = (Canvas)wp.Children[4] would get the 5th canvas in the WrapPanel. TextBox t = (TextBox)c.Children[0] would get the textbox.

Comment: @KMC: Added to my answer to explain

Comment: a slight issue in your code. The index of the WrapPanel could be different that of the list. E.g. If I remove an item in a List, the List index would re-arrange, but WrapPanel would simply have an empty item where it is removed. How do I synchronize the two indexes?

Answer (score 1):

Just operate directly on the `WrapPanel`'s Children collection.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{        

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddCanvasToWrapPanel(this.TestWrapPanel);
        RemoveLastCanvasFromWrapPanel(this.TestWrapPanel);
        AddCanvasToWrapPanel(this.TestWrapPanel);
        DestroyCanvasAtWrapPanelIndex(this.TestWrapPanel, 0);

    }

    private void AddCanvasToWrapPanel(WrapPanel wp)
    {
        TextBox t = new TextBox();
        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        c.Children.Add(t);
        wp.Children.Add(c);
    }

    private void RemoveLastCanvasFromWrapPanel(WrapPanel wp)
    {
        wp.Children.RemoveAt(wp.Children.Count - 1);
    }

    private void DestroyCanvasAtWrapPanelIndex(WrapPanel wp, int index)
    {
        wp.Children.RemoveAt(index);
    }


}
}
```