# Access to UIElement.Properties in a List<UIElement>

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, list, uielement

I'm creating multiple `Canvas` in run time, and each `Canvas` has a `TextBox` as Children. These `Canvas` are Children of a `WrapPanel`. My code is as follow:

```
List<Canvas> cvList = new List<Canvas>();
WrapPanel wp = new WrapPanel();

// function (e.g. a Click event) to add a Canvas with a TextBox
Canvas cv = new Canvas();
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
cv.Children.Add(tb);
cvList.Add(cv);
wp.Children.Add(cv);
```

If after the function is processed 10 times and 10 Canvas is create, I need to change the Text of one specific UIElement (e.g. the 5th TextBox). How would I do so? There is no index to use like that in an array.

**[Edit]**
If I have a button click event also generated in run-time, each button will close its corresponding Canvas:

```
List<Button> btnList = new List<Button>();

// function to add Canvas with a Button
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Content = "Destroy";
btn.Click += destroy_Click;
btnList.Add(btn);
cv.Children.Add(btn);

// Destroy click event
private void destroy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
if (sender == ????)
{}
}
```

What should I compare my sender to?

Comment: "There is no index to use like that in an array."  Yes, there is.  List has an index *exactly* like array: `cvList[4]`.  So does UIElementCollection (which is what Canvas.Children is): `cvList[4].Children[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was trying to explain in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534088/dynamic-and-immutable-uielement-arrays) (which you probably just should have updated) you don't need a separate list, just use the `WrapPanel` directly to access its children - You know you only added `Canvas` elements to your `WrapPanel` so you can cast appropriately:

```
TextBox textbox = (wp.Children[5] as Canvas).Children[0] as TextBox;
textbox.Text = "Hello";
```

Comment: thanks, I though it will be more appropriate to separate the question. Also I edited my question to explain my problem I had with a click event of a UIElement in a List.